# Tradingview Pinescript strategy.close() strategy.exit() coemment problem

Tags: bots, comments, pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm taring to adjust the strategy on Tradingview to work together with bot using alerts (tradingview).

My problem is that comments have to be the same in strategy.close and strategy.exit

There is any possibility that script will automatically when the condition will be fulfilled for strategy.close to take the comment from strategy.exit ?

Many thanks for help and all the best for You!

```
/ === STRATEGY - LONG POSITION EXECUTION ===
strategy.entry(id = "Buy", long = true, when = buy[shunt]==1, comment = "ENTER-LONG_BINANCE-FUTURES_ETHBUSD_ETH_30M_9c621" )

strategy.close(id = "Buy", when = direction[shunt]!=direction[shunt+1], comment = "EXIT-LONG_BINANCE-FUTURES_ETHBUSD_ETH_30M_9c21")

// === STRATEGY - SHORT POSITION EXECUTION ===
strategy.entry(id = "Sell", long = false, when = sell[shunt]==1, comment = "ENTER-SHORT_BINANCE-FUTURES_ETHBUSD_ETH_30M_9c621")

strategy.close(id = "Sell", when = direction[shunt]!=direction[shunt+1], comment = "EXIT-SHORT_BINANCE-FUTURES_ETHBUSD_ETH_30M_9c621")

// === STRATEGY RISK MANAGEMENT EXECUTION ===
strategy.exit("Exit Buy", from_entry = "Buy", profit = useTakeProfit, loss = useStopLoss, trail_points = useTrailStop, trail_offset = useTrailOffset, comment = "EXIT-LONG_BINANCE-FUTURES_ETHBUSD_ETH_30M_9c6c021")

strategy.exit("Exit Sell", from_entry = "Sell", profit = useTakeProfit, loss = useStopLoss, trail_points = useTrailStop, trail_offset = useTrailOffset, comment = "EXIT-SHORT_BINANCE-FUTURES_ETHBUSD_ETH_30M_9c6c021")
```

Error

```
9:23:54 AM — Compilation error. Line 194: Cannot call `strategy.close` with arguments (literal__string, fun_call__operator !=, literal__string); available overloads: strategy.close(literal__string, series__bool) => void;
line 198: Cannot call `strategy.close` with arguments (literal__string, fun_call__operator !=, literal__string); available overloads: strategy.close(literal__string, series__bool) => void
```

There is any possibility that script will automatically when the condition will be fulfilled for strategy.close to take the comment from strategy.exit ?

Many thanks for help and all the best for You!

Comment: What does it mean ??? 'There is any possibility that script will automatically when the condition will be fulfilled for strategy.close to take the comment from strategy.exit ' ???

Comment: Hello, in simple word I would like to have the same comment in strategy.exit and strategy.close :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't come from the comments.
You can use the same comments, no problem. 
Your error comes from :

```
 when = direction[shunt]!=direction[shunt+1]
```

in your strategy.close order.
Please update to pinescript v5 and do not use 'when' in your strategy.close, but put your strategy.close in an 'if' block.